# Cannot access certain columns in my object (RStudio)

Tags: r, stl

I have a text file.
(you can download it here
https://kaggle2.blob.core.windows.net/forum-message-attachments/161748/5933/bibsonomy.txt) (I have not yet received an answer on kaggle, thats why I ask here. Is it possible to attach files to a post here? It may help to support posts and to make them more understandable)

Then I transform that text file to a timeseries in the code below.

```
original <- read.csv(file="bibsonomy.txt", header = FALSE,     col.names=c("timestamps",     "arrivalrates"), comment.char=";")
y <- original[,2]
bibTS <- ts(y,frequency=96)
```

Then I apply the stl() function of the strucchange package on that.

```
require(strucchange)
stl.bib<-stl(bibTS,"periodic",t.jump=96)
```

When printing stl.bib you see that stl.bib has 3 columns. I searched online and found http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/list

So, I should access the second column like this:

```
stl.bib[2]
```

But the values displayed are wrong. Why? And how can I access the second column?Thank you for your help!

Cheers, Benno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three columns you referenced are in the `time.series` component of the returned object.  To access values in the second column, you could use `stl.bib$time.series[,2]`.